# Can't launch Anaconda Navigator from command line nor is there a shortcut in the menu. What happened?

Tags: python, anaconda

In Linux Mint 18.1 the following is what I get when I try to launch Anaconda Navigator today. It worked last night:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'anaconda' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are launching anaconda navigator from the python shell.
You have to first exit the shell in order to launch anaconda navigator.
You can exit shell with:

```
exit()
```

or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

In the command line, you can then type:

```
anaconda-navigator
```